# Wordpress, show current category of the current custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

i have current custom post type 'Portfolio' with 2 categories 'Cat1' and 'Cat2'.

Each post has a Category selected.

```
example:
title: title1, category: Cat1
title: title2, category: Cat2
```

When viewing each post in the front, i want to know what the category this post belong.

for example.. i hav a page **http://www.domain.com/portfolio/title1/** - in this page, i would like to know what category belongs this current post.

should have a section i can display the **Cat1**.

what wordpress function i'm going to use to achieve this?

i have this function.

```
print_r($wp_query->get_queried_object());
```

but it didn't show the current category of this current custom post type.

I hope i explain well.  Any help really appreciated.

Noie

Answer (score 2):

This will return the ID of the current taxonomy of the current post:

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-post-taxonomy', array('fields'=>'ids'));
$term_id = array_pop( $terms ); //gets the last ID in the array
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms for a reference on wp_get_object_terms()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php $cat_name = get_the_category( $post->ID );
 print_r($cat_name);
 ?>
```

Comment: result is empty array, or Array ( )

Comment: pass the post id in $post->ID

Comment: how? i use this $cat_name = get_the_category( $wp_query->queried_object->ID ); print_r($cat_name); still not working...

Comment: got it... i made a custom query under functions.php with the help of this relationship i found. http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-23-database-structure-for-categories/

Comment: @noister unfortunately the link you posted is to a website with a Trojan virus on it, so I recommend deleting your comment. It's a shame, as I need to solve exactly the same problem you solved. So many years ago!